# Working with large views in Xcode and Interface Builder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scrollview, xcode5

I am new to Xcode and I'm currently working with a view which is rather large. I am using a scroll view which works perfectly when I run the application, however I find it difficult to work with such a large view in interface builder. Is there any tricks such as making the working area in Interface Builder larger? Or should I simply stop using interface builder and instantiate the GUI-components programatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your view size to `freeform` and set its size to anything you like just for looking at it and then set it back to its original size

Comment: I share the opinion that one should strive for compact design, but in this case the view just has to contain a large amount of information.

I think you misunderstood the question, you trick just makes the whole IB bigger, I just want to be able to screen which represents the iphone screen vertically longer so that I can see what the user sees when scrolling down.

Comment: oh... In that case you can try changing your view size to "freeform" and set its size to anything you like just for looking at it and then set it back to its original size. Other than that I am not aware of another way other then running it on the simulator/device

Comment: Damn, when I set it back from freeform the layout got all messed up, so can't use it :/.

Comment: I'll try to figure this interesting challenge once I get back home... or unless someone comes with a better solution :).

Answer (score 0):

There are buttons in the upper right corner of the project window toolbar that will hide the navigator and inspector.

[image]

Click the left button to hide the navigator. Click the right button to hide the inspector. Hiding the navigator and inspector will give you more room for the Interface Builder canvas. I recommend starting by hiding the navigator because Interface Builder uses the inspector for many tasks.

Another way to get more room for the canvas is to use the icon view for the object list, which is to the left of the canvas. There is a button in the lower left corner of the canvas that toggles the icon and hierarchical views of the object list.